# Derived template class constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, constexpr, derived

I am trying to derive class with constexpr constructor from template class, which has constexpr constructor to. Derived class defines only constructor. I got this error...

```
main.h

template <class T>
class ExprTemplate
{
public:
const T a;
constexpr ExprTemplate (const T in):a(in){}
constexpr T GetA() const {return a;}
};

class DelivExpr : public ExprTemplate<int>
{
    public:
        constexpr DelivExpr(const int in): ExprTemplate<int> (in){}

};

template <int n>
struct constN
{
    constN() {i = n;}
        uint32_t i;
};


main.cpp

int main()
{
    constN  <   1                               >       e0;//OK
    constN  <   (ExprTemplate<int>(0)).GetA()   >       e1;//OK

    constN  <   (DelivExpr(0)).GetA()           >       e2;
//error, function call must have a constant value in a constant expression

    constexpr DelivExpr deliv(0);
    constN  <   deliv.GetA()                    >       e3;//OK!!!
}
```

Can anyone help please?)

Comment: You're probably missing const specifier of `Get` member function. Try declaring `constexpr T GetA() const {return a;}` in your `ExprTemplate` class.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I cannot reproduce the errors you get...

Comment: @Holt without const method qualifier I more or less similar error (but probably also more verbose:)) on [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/S0ASgG5QRIpwsATe)

Comment: @W.F. I have a similar error, but according to OP's comment, error is for  `e2`, not `e3`... I am simply wondering if this is a mistake in OP's comments, or a compiler difference.

Comment: @Holt oh, true... most probably I missed the actual line :D

Comment: @W.F. Yes, the "const" was missed. I missed it when writing this example. But the error is the same(

Comment: I'm using Keil uVision 5.16. How can I got the complier name/version?

Comment: @Aleksorik I am not familiar with uVision, so I don't know... But it's probably armcc, so it may be a compiler bug...

Comment: Thank's I'll try to update uVision. Hope it will help:)